# Exercise 1.5.7 in Guillemin and Pollack

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, transversality

The problem and its solution is given below:

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

I am wondering if we can solve it without using 1.5.5 ?

Comment: I don't see why you would want to. 1.5.5 is precisely the linear algebra statement you want for this.

Comment: The solution above wanted it ..... and I can not understand why @MikeMiller

Comment: Now I know its importance .......we require the elements to be in $T_{z}(W)$ to prove the required.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to you (if you understand the comment) to rephrase the condition that $f\colon X\to Y$ is transverse to $Z$ by saying instead that for every $x\in f^{-1}(Z)$, the induced mapping $df_x\colon T_xX \to T_{f(x)}Y  \to T_{f(x)}Y/T_{f(x)}Z$ is surjective.

Comment: @TedShifrin I did not understand the comment.

Comment: If you don't know about quotient vector spaces, ignore the comment.

Comment: I know about them but seems like I am not understanding what you want to say in words@TedShifrin